# How to create a drag & drop sorting interface programmatically?

Tags: views

If you have seen the **Views** module, there is "**sorting criteria**", where we add fields and then rearrange fields to set the priority. In order to rearrange, we click on "**rearrange**" link and all fields get a **draggable** UI so that we can move it up or down to set sorting priority.

**How can I do this thing exactly programmatically?**

Comment: Planing to implement it in a **view** or in **form**...??

Comment: Implementing it in a ctool modal. Form actually, that opens up in popup.

Comment: So, you don't want to use Draggable Views? https://www.drupal.org/project/draggableviews

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [drupal_add_tabledrag](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_tabledrag/7) function using which you can add draggable functionality programmatically.

> Assists in adding the tableDrag JavaScript behavior to a themed table.
>
> Draggable tables should be used wherever an outline or list of
>   sortable items needs to be arranged by an end-user. Draggable tables
>   are very flexible and can manipulate the value of form elements placed
>   within individual columns.

See [this blog](http://www.curveagency.com/blog/creating-form-draggable-elements-using-drupaladdtabledrag) for example. You may need to imprement theme function.

```
$element = $vars['element'];
drupal_add_tabledrag('sample_table', 'order', 'sibling', 'item-row-weight');

$header = array(
  'label' => t('Attribute'), 
  'checkbox' => t('Enabled/disabled'),
  'weight' => t('Weight'),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are the 3 simple steps to create a form with drag and drop ordering:

> 1. Implement hook_menu, to register the URL of the form

```
function module_name_menu() {
$items = array();
$items['admin/config/content/module_name/manage'] = array(
    'title' => 'Recent News: List Links',   
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('module_name_manage'),
    'access arguments' => array('access administration pages'),
);
}
```

> We will use the following function to render the form:

```
function module_name_manage() {
$db_result = db_query( "select id,title position from recent_news order by position");   
// create array and add one element called data
$rows= array();
$form['#tree'] = TRUE;
$max = 60;
foreach($db_result as $row){   
    $title = $row->title;
    if(strlen($title)>$max)
        $title = substr($title,0,$max).' ...';
    $form['slides'][$row->id]['id'] = array(
        '#type' => 'hidden',      
        '#default_value' => $row->id,       
    );
    // Textfield to hold content id.
    $form['slides'][$row->id]['title'] = array(
        '#type' => 'item',        
        '#title' => $title
    );     
    // This field is invisible, but contains sort info (weights).
    $form['slides'][$row->id]['weight'] = array(
        '#type' => 'weight',
        '#title' => t('Weight'),
        '#title_display' => 'invisible',
        '#default_value' => $row->position,
    );
}

$form['submit'] = array('#type' => 'submit', '#value' => t('Save changes'));
return $form;
}
```

> 2. implement hook_theme, to register theme implementation of form with drag and drop support

```
function module_name_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
return array(
    'module_name_manage' => array(
        'render element' => 'form',
    ),
);
}
```

> And here is the callback function which will render the form with drag
>   and drop capabilities

```
function theme_module_name_manage($variables) {
$form = $variables['form'];

$rows = array();
foreach (element_children($form['slides']) as $nid) {
    $form['slides'][$nid]['weight']['#attributes']['class'] = array('slides-order-weight');
    $rows[] = array(
        'data' => array(
            array('class' => array('slide-cross')),               
                drupal_render($form['slides'][$nid]['title']),
                drupal_render($form['slides'][$nid]['weight']),       
            ),
        'class' => array('draggable'),
    );
}

$header = array('',t('title'),t('position'));
$output = drupal_render($form['note']);
$output .= theme('table', array('header' => $header, 'rows' => $rows, 'attributes' => array('id' => 'slides-order')));
$output .= drupal_render_children($form);

drupal_add_tabledrag('slides-order', 'order', 'sibling', 'slides-order-weight');

return $output;
}
```

> 3. Implement hook_submit, to handle form submit and save the ordering

```
function module_name_manage_submit($form, &$form_state) {
$slides = array(); 
foreach ($form_state['values']['slides'] as $slide) {   
    $slides[] = array(
        'id' => $slide['id'],       
        'weight' => $slide['weight'],
    );         
}  
if (!empty($slides)) {
    usort($slides, '_module_name_arraysort');
}  
$position = 1;
foreach($slides as $slide){
    $id = $slide['id'];
    $sql = "UPDATE recent_news SET position={$position} WHERE id = {$id}";
    db_query($sql);
    $position++;
}

drupal_set_message(t('Ordering have been saved.'));
}

// Custom array sort function by weight.
function _module_name_arraysort($a, $b) {
if (isset($a['weight']) && isset($b['weight'])) {
    return $a['weight'] < $b['weight'] ? -1 : 1;
}
return 0;
}
```

The code is quite long but you can just copy and paste then modify it if necessary. This tutorial is based on Ki Kim's post on http://www.urbaninsight.com/2012/09/11/creating-table-with-draggable-weights-in-drupal-7